# iphone, ipad javascript fadein

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, scroll, fadein

I am testing my website on my iphone and ipad and there is an instance in the javascript and code where when you reach to the end of a slice, certain elements should drop down and fade in. unfortunately this is not working only on ipad and iphone.

can someone help me out? here is my code:

HTML:

```
    <div class="hideme">
        <img class="cow" src="http://assets.daddario.com/html_fragments/images/calftone_cow_circle.png" alt="cow">
        <img class="texture" src="http://assets.daddario.com/html_fragments/images/calftone_texture_circle.png" alt="texture">
        <img class="threeSixty" src="http://assets.daddario.com/html_fragments/images/calftone_360_circle.png" alt="360round">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.hideme
{
   position: absolute;
   opacity:0;
   margin-top: 250px;
}
.cow
{
   position: absolute;
   margin-top: 380px;
   margin-left: 88px;
}

.texture
{
   position: absolute;
   margin-top: 380px;
   margin-left: 402px;  
}
.threeSixty
{
   position: absolute;
   margin-top: 380px;
   margin-left: 717px;  
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.hideme').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

        }

    }); 

});
```

});

Comment: You don't need the `.each()` method if there's only one class of `.hideme`.

Comment: it works fine in all browsers and IE. I'm just looking for the reason why it wont work on only iphone and ipad.